# Retrofit + Moshi + Kotlin = 403 Error when trying to get Json Object

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

I'm trying to get a JsonObject with Retrofit using Moshi to parse, but keep encountering a 403 error. I can access the request from my browser, so I'm pretty sure I'm just doing something wrong in my setup here..

```
object RetrofitFactory {
    private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

    fun makeRetrofitService(): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .baseUrl("http://url.to.destination/")
            .build()

}

interface MyApiService {
    @GET("products.json")
    fun getPropertiesAsync(): Deferred<List<ProductProperty>>
}

object MyApi {
    val retrofitService: MyApiService by lazy {
        RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService().create(MyApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

The JsonObject (products.json) itself starts with an outer object "outer" like so:

```
{
  outer : [
    {inner object1},
    {inner object2},
    {inner object3}
  ]
}
```

but trying to get "products.json/outer" yields 403 error, while trying to get "products.json" says: 
`com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the error gives a solution. You are trying to access an array but it is an object.

Comment: Yes, but is there a different way to access the object that I'm not seeing listed in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: try with this `fun getPropertiesAsync(): Deferred<ProductProperty>`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a class that have the `outer` field. Because `outer` is an object.

```
class ProductsBody (
    @Json("outer")
    var outer: List<ProductProperty>? = null
)

interface MyApiService {
    @GET("products.json")
    fun getPropertiesAsync(): Deferred<ProductsBody> // @NOTE the change here
}
```